# Mariehamn Airport Transfer

Tags: airport-transfer, aland, mhq, mariehamn

How do you get from Mariehamn Airport to Mariehamn, and vice-versa?

When I was flying from MHQ I looked up the distance on the map and decided to take a walk there since it was only 40 minutes by foot. Aren't there any airport coaches, maybe operated by Viking Bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By foot or taxi. There is no regular, scheduled public transport between the airport and the city centre.

[image: Walking path to Mariehamn Airport (MHQ)]

Comment: Taxi seems to be less than 15€ according to the [Mariehamn Taxi Pricelist](https://www.mariehamnstaxi.com/priser/).